# React - Summernote is showing the wrong view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, summernote

I am using Summernote for rich editor

Here is the screenshot of the view:
[image]

CodeSandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-goldberg-1enlf

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactSummernote from "react-summernote";
import "react-summernote/dist/react-summernote.css"; // import styles

// Import bootstrap(v3 or v4) dependencies
import "bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown";
import "bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip";
import "bootstrap/js/dist/modal";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

class RichTextEditor extends Component {
  onChange(content) {
    console.log("onChange", content);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactSummernote
        value="Default value"
        options={{
          height: 350,
          dialogsInBody: true,
          toolbar: [
            ["style", ["style"]],
            ["font", ["bold", "underline", "clear"]],
            ["fontname", ["fontname"]],
            ["para", ["ul", "ol", "paragraph"]],
            ["table", ["table"]],
            ["insert", ["link", "picture", "video"]],
            ["view", ["fullscreen", "codeview"]]
          ]
        }}
        onChange={this.onChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default RichTextEditor;
```

I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: Looks like a CSS file isn't being loaded, have you verified that the CSS has in fact loaded? Because clearly none of the icons have (disclaimer I've never used Summernote, just trying to help)

Comment: yea I believe that is the case, but which one isn't loaded that I would like to know , and thanks for trying help me

Comment: I had a quick look at the Summernote demo page, and it looks like the icons are pulled from the `summernote.css` file, which appears to be getting [imported](https://github.com/summernote/react-summernote/blob/master/src/Summernote.jsx#L4) therefore should load when that file is loaded. Do you get the same behaviour locally? I can see the relevant CSS file is loaded but it's within an iFrame (which could be the problem).

Comment: yea its working locally